# CloudFormation userdata to create a RedHat user

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

How to create a user on redhat instance during the launch? I tried include the following commands in the user data but didn't work. Any idea why? or is there another way of creating a user using userdata?

```
sudo su
useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/testuser  -g root testuser
echo P@ssc0deT3st | passwd testuser --stdin
sed -re 's/^(PasswordAuthentication)([[:space:]]+)no/\1\2yes/' -i.`date -I` /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": {
    "Fn::Join": ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
      "useradd -d /home/testuser -g root -m -s /bin/bash testuser", "\n",
    ]]
  }
}
```

Although I'm not sure if you're allowed to add a user to the group root, but that's not here nor there. You can then add the rest of your commands in the same fashion as the useradd command in my example.

Note that sometimes it takes a couple of minutes for the UserData to execute so give it a couple of minutes after the instance is up and running. Also you can you check for errors in /var/log in cmd-init.log I believe.

Make sure to test your commands on a running instance to make sure they work before trying them in the stack it'll save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you use Amazon's ami. Only few ami's support UserData. UserData is run as root.